# Add param to API POST request

Tags: external-api

I need to query this endpoint
'''https://******com/api/payments/{payment_id}/refund'''

Because it is a post request, I assume that the payment_id param needs to be in the body of the request.
How do I add that parameter? Because it is in the middle of the url I do not know how to do it.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

`payment_id` appears to be part of the URL, rather than a parameter of the body. You can simply send the POST request to the URL, replacing `{payment_id}` with the actual ID to use, in the URL itself, e.g. `https://endpoint/api/payments/12345/refund`.